# User name while using windows 7 Remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Got my old laptop installed with Windows 7 Professional. While creating user I put my full name as Mahesh M. Kadam and completed the procedure.I feel as this laptop is going to be used at only home so putting full name would not be appropriate so changed account name to Mahesh. But while using Windows Remote Desktop I can't log in with new user name and password but able to log in or connect to my laptop with old user name. I'm not going for static IP address so I've to type in my full name every time i'm logging in which bit cumbersome.Solution tried given at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2454362/renaming-a-user-account-does-not-automatically-change-the-profile-path and kept as it is. So any any way to rectify this?

Comment: You cannot pings users like that.  If it helps you should upvote their answer instead of submitting a comment.  You don't have to create a new username, if you specify which machine the user belongs to, you can use an account that exists on the remote account.

Comment: So should i take it down? Asking for help. Happy to follow

Comment: You should not delete perfectly valid questions.  Since an existing question's answer helped you, this should be closed as a duplicate of that question, and you should upvote the existing answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109854/discussion-between-the-dentist-and-ramhound).